# Writing where clause using count in subquery in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, count, eloquent, subquery

I want to write this query using eloquent in Laravel.

```
select * 
from tbl_lawyers as l
where ( select count(*) 
        from cooprations as c
        where c.fk_lawyer_id = l.lawyer_id
        and c.fk_coopration_id in ($request->cooprations))>= count($request->cooprations);
```

How should I write it?

I wrote it with `>=`, but that does not work.

```
$query->join('tbl_lawyer_cooperation', function ($s) use ($request) {
    $s->on('tbl_lawyer_cooperation.fk_lawyer_id', '=', 'vw_lawyers.lawyer_id')
        ->where(function ($d) use ($request) {
            $d->select('count')
                ->whereIn('tbl_lawyer_cooperation.fk_cooperation_id', $request->cooprations);
        },'>=',count($request->cooprations));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
->where(DB::raw(count($request->cooprations)), '<=', function ($d) use ($request) {
    $d->selectRaw('count(*)')
        ->from('cooprations')
        ->whereIn('tbl_lawyer_cooperation.fk_cooperation_id', $request->cooprations);
});
```

The raw expression is not ideal, but it works. I'm not sure there's a better way to do this.